# Oracle Create View not working

Tags: oracle

Good afternoon.  I'm doing an exercise in Oracle. To my knowledge this query should be correct, however; I always get a "statement isn't ended appropriately error".  I have the  Create View, Select, FROM, Joins all correct.  Why is this statement not working?

```
CREATE VIEW RESERVATION_CUSTOMER AS
SELECT r.RESERVATION_ID, r.TRIP_ID, r.TRIP_DATE, c.CUSTOMER_NUM, c.LAST_NAME, c.FIRST_NAME, c.PHONE
FROM RESERVATION AS r
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER AS c ON c.CUSTOMER_NUM=r.CUSTOMER_NUM;
```

Comment: `AS` is used to define column aliases, not the table. Remove that from `FROM RESERVATION AS r` and `INNER JOIN CUSTOMER AS c`.

Answer (score -1):

Try it

```
CREATE VIEW RESERVATION_CUSTOMER AS
SELECT r.RESERVATION_ID, r.TRIP_ID, r.TRIP_DATE, 
       c.CUSTOMER_NUM, c.LAST_NAME, c.FIRST_NAME, c.PHONE
FROM RESERVATION r, CUSTOMER c
WHERE r.CUSTOMER_NUM = c.CUSTOMER_NUM;
```

for more information about views link bellow

[enter link description here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm)